# Unable to get cross domain cookies

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

How to get all the cookies of other domain (including third party cookies) and i am using laravel dusk.

My code snippet

```
    $browser = new Browser($driver);
    $driver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:9515', $capabilities);
    $browser->visit('mydomain'); 
    $cookiesData = ($driver->manage()->getCookies());
```

I only get cookies related to mydomain..Unable to get third party cookies